# notify.js doesn't show notification if another window is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [notify.js](https://github.com/alexgibson/notify.js) widget on a custom designed website. The notification is supposed to be shown to user when the loaded data from a php file has the value "1". I used setInterval method as I want to reload the function every 5 seconds.
For example:

```
    setInterval(function(){
    $('.orders-undelivered').load("undelivered-orders.php");
    var orders = $('.orders-undelivered').text();
    if (orders == "1"){
        function onShowNotification () {
        console.log('notification is shown!');
        }
        function onCloseNotification () {
            console.log('notification is closed!');
        }

        function onClickNotification () {
            console.log('notification was clicked!');
            window.location.href='http://mywebsite.com/admin'
        }

        function onErrorNotification () {
            console.error('Error showing notification. You may need to request permission.');
        }
        function doNotification () {
            var myNotification = new Notify('New Order', {
                body: 'Click here',
                tag: 'My unique id',
                icon:'http://mywebsite.com/images/logo.gif',
                notifyShow: onShowNotification,
                notifyClose: onCloseNotification,
                notifyClick: onClickNotification,
                notifyError: onErrorNotification,
                timeout: 4
            });

            myNotification.show();
        }
    }
),5000}
```

It works perfect until I open other windows or tabs and a couple of programmes in my pc. After that, the notification doesn't open. In order to view the notification I have to click on the tab where the notify.js runs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need declare the notifyJs into the index of the website or make that into each view.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Actually It is into the index of administration folder. There is only one page in the admin folder with constant functions in footer scripts (notify.js runs here) and <head>. The content is dynamically loaded by queries with javascript in the main <div> of the page. So the widget is into the index page and runs constantly.

Comment: No I haven't tried this one. I am using this: https://github.com/alexgibson/notify.js

Comment: The one you suggest me it's not seem to be a desktop notification. What I want is the user be notified on his Desktop (like notify.js) even if he is browsing in anoter window or tab. The problem, as I said, is that after a couple of hours the notification doesn't show up and you have to click on the tab in order to view it.